# Rails remote calls from javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building a totally custom photo gallery for my new personal website. I have a Photo Show view which has next and previous buttons, these have "remote: true" set on the links so it does the call in the background which then renders a javascript view which updates the photo on the page.

Now, I have a fullscreen button on my Show view which opens the fullscreen action on my Photos controller.

I wish to add previous and next functionality on here based on which way a user drags the photo in view. (Dragging is working fine). At a certain point of the drag I obviously need to perform a call to grab the next Photo or the previous Photo (dependent upon drag direction) but this time the call will be from within javascript itself.

How do I go about doing this and getting the controller to return the correct information as (thinking about it), I will require the URL of the photo, it's title, it's ID, and maybe the id of the album it's in.

Any ideas?

Comment: The general idea would be to store whatever information you need within hidden fields or attribute tags in your form. If you can add a callback to the dragging and know which way to go (next or prev), then make an explicit AJAX request and have the corresponding returned JS update the view. You can also use a JS "class" if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Further to `MrDanA`'s comment, you'll need to store the attributes you require somewhere in your relevant HTML. To keep things clean, I would just append them to the `image_tag` in rails, like this:

```
<%= image_tag "location", data: { title: "", id: "", album: "" } %>
```

This will allow you to give each image a distinct array of `data` attributes, which you can then reference in your JS

Then you'll just need to create an ajax call when you're dragging the image, to call the next or previous. As to how to do this, I'm not entirely sure the exact code, but I'd basically look for an event handler in the dragging library you're using, which will allow you to trigger an ajax request

This request will allow you to ping a controller action, which can return the relevant image for you. If you give us some more code, we'll be in a much better position to help!